# toggle display of images from an API

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, url

Please bear with me, i'm very new to coding.

I've loaded two images from an API (randomPrint1 and randomPrint2), but they both display at the same time. How do I preload these images successfully and display them in the draw function when I want to?

Ideally, I'd have a different image (from the API) display each time I click on the page. I want to be able to format the display of the page in javascript too if that's possible.

Thanks! Here's the code I have so far in js and html:

js:

```
randomPrint1 = ["https://api.harvardartmuseums.org/object?apikey=f26d41e3-69ac-4735-9027-0d4607177a6a&size=1&page=512"];
randomPrint2 = ["https://api.harvardartmuseums.org/object?apikey=f26d41e3-69ac-4735-9027-0d4607177a6a&size=1&page=2115"];

const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * [randomPrint1, randomPrint2].length);
//console.log(random, randomPrint1[random]);
let baseimageurl;
let img = [randomPrint1[0,1], randomPrint2[0,1]];




function preload(){}
fetch(randomPrint1)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log("success!", res))
  .catch(err => console.log("something went wrong...", err));


    fetch(randomPrint1)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
 //console.log(response)
        resPrints = response
        let randomPrint1 = document.querySelector("#randomPrint1")
        for(i=0; i<resPrints.records.length; i++){
            //console.log(resPrints)
            let printsElement = document.createElement("img")
            if (resPrints.records[i].images.length>0){
                printsElement.setAttribute("src", resPrints.records[i].images[0].baseimageurl)
                printsElement.setAttribute("width", 290)
                printsElement.setAttribute("height", 200)
                randomPrint1.appendChild(printsElement)}
            }
    })

    fetch(randomPrint2)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log("success!", res))
    .catch(err => console.log("something went wrong...", err));
  
  
      fetch(randomPrint2)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
   //console.log(response)
          resPrints = response
          let randomPrint2 = document.querySelector("#randomPrint1")
          for(i=0; i<resPrints.records.length; i++){
              //console.log(resPrints)
              let printsElement = document.createElement("img")
              if (resPrints.records[i].images.length>0){
                  printsElement.setAttribute("src", resPrints.records[i].images[0].baseimageurl)
                  printsElement.setAttribute("width", 290)
                  printsElement.setAttribute("height", 200)
                  randomPrint2.appendChild(printsElement)
              }
   
          }
      })
 
      
function setup(){
createCanvas(400, 400);
background(200);
}


function draw(){

}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <Main> 
 </Main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    <div id="randomPrint1">
    </div>
 <div id="randomPrint2">
 </div>
 
    <script src="sketch.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

I've moved the 'fetch' around, and tried to toggle the display of the URLs. Tried to treat the URLs as an image and load them in the draw function. No luck.

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're trying to do. Do you want to halt the image loading / wait for a click anywhere on the page, in order to initiate the API call? Also - *Ideally, I'd have a different image (from the API) display each time I click on the page* - click where? Or do you mean when you load the page?

Comment: hi, i want to wait for a click anywhere on the page to initiate the API call and change the image.